# Route to proper index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm having issues with my Codeigniter `.htaccess` file... basically it goes like this.

Regular .htaccess file (that works on my localhost):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The website folder structure where I'm putting all my files:

```
website.com/
    css/
    js/
    img/
    index.html
    dev/
        application/
        assets/
        system/
        index.php
        .htaccess <<< A problem now exists with this file
```

The website is now trying to load the `index.html` file when I go to `website.com/dev/` **instead** of the `index.php` file.

I've tried different variations of the `.htaccess` file but I either get a 500 server error or the `index.html` file.

How can I route `website.com/dev/` to the proper `index.php` file?

Thanks in advance!
Vincent Wilkie

---

### Update

---

I've got a partly working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/dev/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is only partly working because the URL's now show `.../dev/index.php/controller/method/args`

I know the whole point of using `mod_rewrite` is to remove the `index.php` from the URL ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have that directory structure? Because adopting that structure isn't recommended and could mean you run into quite a few problems  Instead you want to have a directory structure like

```
website.com/
    application/
    system/
    assets/
        css/
        js/
        img/
        index.php
        .htaccess
```

You want to place your `application` and `system` directories a level higher than your web root (`assets`) so that they are not publicly accessible which is much better from a security perspective.

Comment: The reason for this directory structure is because the root directory (aka `website.com/`) is already in use for something else. It's also based on the `CodeIgniter PHP Framework` which places `.htaccess` and `index.php` in a specific location and is what is used by all our developers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same directory structure. Try this.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

NOTE: I assume you use the site as **`website.com/dev/`**

Hope this helps :)